# How do I mention user in teams channel incoming webhook?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-teams

I am unable to find any documentation available where I can mention a user for every message sent in a teams channel. I have to use an incoming webhook to send messages to the channel.
The messages will be sent from an azure function. This is the code I have tried so far.

```
axios
    .post(
      'https://name.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx@xyz/IncomingWebhook/xxx/xxxb',
      {
        '@type': 'MessageCard',
        '@context': 'http://schema.org/extensions',
        themeColor: '0072C6', // light blue
        summary: 'Summary description',
        sections: [
          {
            activityTitle: title,
            text: message
          }
        ]
      }
    )
    .then(
      (resolvedValue) => {
        resolve(`Sent message to teams ${resolvedValue}`);
      },
      (error) => {
        reject(error);
      }
    );
```

I want to mention a user so that they get alerted when the message arrives.

Comment: Please go through this documentation to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards which talks about User mention in Incoming Webhook with Adaptive Cards.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT. That worked. Do you know how I can prevent it from truncating the message? It's just limiting the message to one single line.

Comment: Please check this document which talks about formatting in cards - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-markdown

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. Could you answer this question so that I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: Sure, I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through [User mention in Incoming Webhook with Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards) which talks about adding @mentions within an Adaptive Card body for incoming webhooks.

Please check [Format cards with Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-markdown) to add formatting in cards.